# PHP long polling make my server hang

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, nginx

I am trying to make a facebook webpage messenger like app and I use AJAX in client side and php on my server side.

My AJAX code:

```
function longPoll(timestamp)
{
    var queryString = {'timestamp' : timestamp};
    var shouldDelay = false;

    $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            url: 'pollMsg.php',
            data: queryString,
            timeout: 5000,
            cache: false
        }
    ).done(function(data){
        var array = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            $('#msgTable > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td><b>' + array[i].sender + '</b><br/>' + array[i].timestamp + '</td><td><b>' + array[i].title + '</b><br/>' + array[i].content + '</td></tr>');
        }

        longPoll(obj.timestamp);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //shouldDelay = textStatus !== "timeout";
    }).always(function() {
        var delay = shouldDelay ? 5000: 0;
        if (shouldDelay) {
            shouldDelay = false;
            window.setTimeout(longPoll, delay);
        }
    });
}

// initialize jQuery
$(function() {
    longPoll();
});
```

My PHP code:

```
//set php runtime to unlimited
set_time_limit(10);
while (true) {
$last_ajax_call = isset($_GET['timestamp']) ? (int)$_GET['timestamp'] : '1970-01-01 00:00:00';

$sql = "select * from post where (receiver = ? or sender = ?) and postat > str_to_date(?, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s')";
$stmt   = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $username, $username, $last_ajax_call);

$result = $stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all();

if (count($rows) > 0) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $data = array (
            'sender' => $row[3],
            'timestamp' => $row[5],
            'title' => $row[1],
            'content' => $row[2]
        );
        array_push($result, $data);
    }

    $json = json_encode($result);
    echo $json;

    break;
} else {
    sleep( 1 );
    continue;
}
}
```

I found that if I once click on the page with the AJAX code, when I change to other page in the same webserver, I will get a nginx error (as I use nginx).

What is the problem in my code? I have found some example of long polling and it gives me similar code. Thank you.

When I restart php-fpm, everything is okay, which means that I have generated so many request so that the server cannot handle.

Comment: Why don't you use web sockets for implementing the real-time communication part in your messenger rather than long polling? Long polling is an older approach to handling such situation.

Comment: I want to make the app compatible with old browser.

Comment: For implementing Web Sockets, you need to use ```socket.io``` in client side & ```Node JS``` in server side & Socket.io works with most of the browsers.  To know more about socket.to Ref :  http://socket.io/

Comment: Can I use PHP rather than Node.js?

Comment: For Web Socket in PHP check - http://socketo.me/

Comment: Thank you. But I also want to know why my code above cannot work

Comment: Check your Server Log